# Show product options like flavors below each product

Tags: shopify

I am new to shopify and I am looking for any help. I am using the [Simple shopify theme](https://themes.shopify.com/themes/simple/styles/light) and in settings page I displayed my products in Homepage. Now homepage contains product images with prices. What I want to add is the product flavors. I wanted to display each product available below each product located in homepage but don't know where to tweak it. Any help would be much appreciated.

index.liquid

```
{% if settings.home_section_1 != blank %}
  {% include settings.home_section_1 %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`product options`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/product_option) and by tweaking your [`index.liquid`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/templates/index-liquid) file like this:

```
<ul>
{% for product in products limit:10 %}
    <li><a href="{{ product.url}}"><img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'medium' }}" alt=""></a>

    <div>Flavors available:</div>
    <ul>
    {% for option in product.options_with_values %}
        <li>{{ option.name }} : {{ option.values | join ', ' }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In your case, you might have to edit the template liquid file in `/Snippets` selected for `home_section_1` according to your `settings_schema.json`

Comment: Hey, I'll check try this one.

Comment: I added a sample index.liquid in my question above.

Comment: I get it no. I found the it in my `product-grid-item`. Now i'm tweaking it a lil bit.

Comment: My bad. what I wanted to display is the product option like flavors.

Comment: I get it now using the link here https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/how-to-show-all-the-values-of-a-product-option-304649 but it wont display the title instead it displays a word "One Flavor"

Comment: updated the code to use `product.options_with_values` and `option.name`